# GTFS detect same stop in different directions

Tags: gtfs

I have 2 stops, that have different `stop_id` and the same names. They are the same and the only difference is that one goes to direction A and the other one to B. (they are 20m apart)

Is there a way to detect if there are 2 stops that are the same (same routes) but different directions?

I can't search stops with the same name because there are multiple stops with the same `stop_name`. The other idea that I had was to search if there's a stop +/- 10m of this stop with the same name but that's also not correct because there can be a bus and a train stop with the same name but eventually with totally different routes.

Comment: so you want a list of routes (not trips) that visit the same stop at least once in each direction, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of `Routes` *(not `Trips`)* that visit the same `stop_name` more than once, but in more than one `direction_id`...

If your [`Trips.txt`](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#tripstxt) table contains `direction_id` then you could create a query using:

> `Stops.txt`, where you would get:
>
> - `stop_name`
>
> joined to `Stop_times.txt`
>
> - only for a link between `Stops.txt` and `Trips.txt`
>
> joined to `Trips.txt`, where you would get:
>
> - `route_id`
> - a count of each possible `Direction_ID`
> - limit the results to count of `Direction_ID > 1` (for each possible `Direction_ID`)

If necessary with your data, you may have to include `Calendar.txt` to limit to desired days of week and/or current schedules.

### Example SQL:

```
SELECT 
    route_id,
    stop_name
FROM 
    ( Trips 
        LEFT JOIN Stop_times 
            ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id )
        LEFT JOIN Stops 
            ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
GROUP BY 
    route_id,
    stop_name
HAVING Sum(IIf([direction_id]=1,1,0))>0 
    AND Sum(IIf([direction_id]=0,1,0))>0
```

---

### More info:

- [GTFS Trips.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#tripstxt)
- [GTFS direction_id on loops](https://kurtraschke.com/2011/05/gtfs-direction_id-on-loops/)

Comment: No, I want to detect stops in different directions. For example in stops.txt we have 2 stops with the same name and different id, they have equal names because they're the same stop, only one is for north direction routes and other one for south. But we can't do `stop_name1 == stop_name2` because there're few stops with the same name but 3km apart